# Delete IIS authorization rules "All users"

Tags: powershell, iis, authorization

I trying to delete a specific IIS authorization rule from one of our web services.
I need to delete the user "all users" with the mode"allow".

I tried using this command

```
Clear-Webconfiguration -Filter /system.webServer/security/authorization -Force -PSPath 'IIS:\sites\IAI Application Customizer'
```

I can delete all created rules, but only the "all users" rule still exist.

I hope you can help me with this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution.

```js
$webConfigPath = "C:\Users\SOGL_D\Desktop\test.xml"

$xml = [xml](get-content $webConfigPath)   # Create XML object and open the web.config file


foreach( $item in  $xml.configuration."system.webServer".security.authorization.add )  # Traverse through all modules 
{ 
        if( $item.users -eq "*" )                          # Checking if the current module is to be removed 
        { 
           $xml.configuration."system.webServer".security.authorization.RemoveChild($item);   # Remove the desired module when found 
        } 
}

$xml.Save($webConfigPath)   # Save the updated web.config file
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue, which I can reproduce at least with IIS7: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/46cb1905-424e-4bf1-a9e4-514e274b7582/iis-clearwebconfiguration-cmdlet-needs-to-be-executed-twice-for-inherited-url-authorization-rules?forum=winserverpowershell

You have to call `Clear-WebConfiguration` twice to remove all inherited rules. Example:

```
Clear-WebConfiguration -Filter "/system.webServer/security/authorization/add[@users='*' and @roles='' and @verbs='']" -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\my_site"
Clear-WebConfiguration -Filter "/system.webServer/security/authorization/add[@users='*' and @roles='' and @verbs='']" -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\my_site"
Add-WebConfiguration -Filter "/system.webServer/security/authorization" -Value (@{AccessType="Allow"; Users="my_user"; Permissions="Read, Write"}) -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\my_site"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change `web.config` file for that service.

```
<authorization>
    <remove accessType="Allow" users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: I use a aouthomatic pwoershell script. It runs on all servers. So there is noeone who can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config
>   /section:system.webServer/security/authorization
>   /-"[accessType='Allow', users='*']"